# tensorflow variable declaration what does point do?

Tags: tensorflow

when we declare the Tensorflow variable

```
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype = tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype = tf.float32)
```

what does .3 and -.3 mean in this declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the variable with the given array.

Answer (score 0):

For variable `W` the shape will be `.3` in one dimension, same as variable `b` the shape will be `-.3`. Default `dtype` for this tensor is `tf.float32`. So it will be ok if You declare variable like,

```
W = tf.Variable([.3])
b = tf.Variable([-.3])
```

To know more about TensorFlow variables, follow this tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables)

Comment: what does .3 and -.3 shape looks like?

Comment: why they us minus sign on -.3?

Comment: consider X-axis, and the point is located in .3 it has positive distance from initial point 0, while -.3 has negative distance from the initial point 0.